# How do arguments in publish/subscribe pattern work?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, eventemitter

In one place we use eventEmitter to generate events. Actually it's the very common way.

```
eventEmitter.emit('started', data, date);
```

In the other place we try to catch it. Everything is pretty clear when using arrow functions. 'data' and 'date' are passed to the function as arguments

```
someInstanse.event.on('started', (data, date) => {
    //crazy stuff here
})
```

But how this notaion in fact works? We determine 3 args with emitter and now we really have only event string and a function instead

```
someInstance.event.on('started', function(data, date) {
});
```

I suppose that before adding arrow functions it was the only way to call anonymous functions

Comment: Opened the Node docs and read that emit method passes arguments to the listeners. Also every emitter.on(eventName, listener) means that listener is a callback function. So it's not a problem now.

Comment: Are you confused by how the data is passed to the callback functions? or how the eventemitter works under the hood?

Comment: Yes, now I know how to formulate it. I have no clue why `emit` invoked on the client side doesn't cause `emit` on the server. According to publish/subscribe pattern every emit iterates through the listeners' functions and executes them or returns false if array with handles is undefined. I'm trying Socket.IO library so it's only possible to hook `emits` called by the server itself.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. You could consider pub/sub a simple data structure and it cannot communicate directly through front-end and back-end.

Comment: Got it. This way it really works on practice but listeners prepared on the server side are still able to catch these emits so I suggest that library has some mechanism for passing values. Or may be it stores the copy of listners' list on the front-end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the typical publish/subscribe design pattern. And it is really determined by how the `emit` and how subscribers respond to the event are implemented under the hood.

Basically, in the publish function, you want to call every subscriber(on) functions, provided with the information with publish(emit). Below is just some pseudo-code.

```
function publish(type, ...args) {
    // for each of the subscribers of that type
    for (let i = 0; i < pubsub[type].length; i++) {
        // you could do (this provides the listener with type)
        subscribers[i](type, ...args)
        // or you could do (the subscriber doesn't know the type)
        subscriber[i](...args)
    }
}
```

I wrote a minified pub/sub pattern in github, if you want to take a look. I think it's extremely helpful to help you understand this issue.
https://github.com/thomasyimgit/pubsub/blob/master/index.js